# No module named 'PyQt5.QtTextToSpeech'

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6, text-to-speech, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia-jetson-nano

```
Jetson Nano
Ubuntu18.04
Python 3.6.9
PyQt5 Version: 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2
```

PyQt5 installed, use ***apt install xxx***

I tried to excute

```
from PyQt5.QtTextToSpeech import QTextToSpeech
```

I got an error:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5.QtTextToSpeech import QTextToSpeech
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtTextToSpeech'
```

I tried to install

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

but nothing changed.
How can I install the module for my machine.

Comment: For ***recent*** versions of ubuntu, you would need to do: `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qttexttospeech` ([see here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/python3-pyqt5.qttexttospeech)). But that package may not be available in old ubuntu versions like bionic. Note that QtTextToSpeech requires ***at least*** PyQt-5.15.1.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, you are right. I have tried to install ***python3-pyqt5-qtexttospeech*** before, but it prompted that the package was not found. My PyQt5 version is ***Version: 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2***. It seems that QTextToSpeech cannot be used on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try installing the required PyQt5 modules using pip instead.

- Ensure that pip is installed. You can install it using apt if it's
  not already installed:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install python3-pip
  ```
- Then, install PyQt5 using pip:

  ```
  sudo pip3 install pyqt5
  ```

This will install PyQt5 along with all its components, including `QtTextToSpeech`. After installing PyQt5 with `pip`, try importing `QTextToSpeech` again in your Python script:

```
from PyQt5.QtTextToSpeech import QTextToSpeech
```

Comment: I can't install PyQt5 by ***pip*** in Jetson nano. 
***FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-_iizt4a4/pyqt5/setup.py'***

Comment: There's a major problem with this answer. The [PyQt5 binary wheels available via pip](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files) only support ARM64 for MacOSX; for Linux, there's only x86_64. Thus, if you try to install PyQt5 via pip on Jetson Nano (which has an ARM processor), pip will try to compile everything from scratch, since there's no compatible wheel available for that platform.

Comment: @shitianxie No problem. Did you see my other comment on your question? It would be helpful if you could confirm whether the `pyqt5.qttexttospeech` package is available on your system (I assume not).